# What are the entire functions $f$ such that $|f'(z)| \leq |f(z)| \ ? $

Tags: complex-analysis

Could someone advise me on how to determine all entire functions $f$ such that $|f'(z)| \leq |f(z)|, \forall z\ ?$

Hints will suffice, thank you.

Comment: There are an infinite amount so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the general fact that if $f,g$ are entire functions with $|f| \leq |g|$, then $f=cg$ with $|c| \leq 1$ (which follows from Liouville's Theorem).

Comment: which means $f=e^{cz}, |c| \leq 1 \ ?$

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo You can multiply by a constant, and it's ok.

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo as Jean-Claude says, you are missing an arbitrary multiplicative constant.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1** Unless $f \equiv 0$, prove that $f$ cannot have any zero. If $z_0$ is a zero of order $m$ for $f$, what happens if you divide both sides by $(z-z_0)^{m-1}$?

**Hint 2** $\frac{f'}{f}$ is entire and bounded.